# Comparing Two DataFrames and Loop through them (to test a condition)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to 'join' two DataFrames based on a condition.

**Condition**

```
if df1.Year == df2.Year & 
df1.Date >= df2.BeginDate or df1.Date <= df2.EndDate &
df1.ID == df2.ID 
#if the condition is True, I would love to add an extra column (binary) to df1, something like
#df1.condition = Yes or No.
```

My data looks like this:

```
df1: 

Year     Week     ID   Date
2020      1      123   2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020      1      345   2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020      2      123   2020-01-07 00:00:00
2020      1      123   2020-01-01 00:00:00


df2: 

Year    BeginDate               EndDate                 ID
2020    2020-01-01  00:00:00    2020-01-02  00:00:00    123
2020    2020-01-01  00:00:00    2020-01-02  00:00:00    123
2020    2020-01-01  00:00:00    2020-01-02  00:00:00    978
2020    2020-09-21  00:00:00    2020-01-02  00:00:00    978


end_df: #Expected output 

Year     Week     ID   Condition
2020      1      123     True  #Year is matching, week1 is between the dates, ID is matching too 
2019      1      345     False #Year is not matching
2020      2      187     False # ID is not matching 
2020      1      123     True  # Same as first row.
```

I thought to solve this by looping over two DataFrames:

```
for row in df1.iterrrows(): 
    for row2 in df2.iterrows(): 
         if row['Year'] == row2['Year2']:
              if row['ID] == row2['ID']: 
                  .....
                  .....
                   row['Condition'] = True 
         else: 
            row['Condition'] = False
```

However... this is leading to error after error.

Really looking forward how you guys will tackle this problem. Many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1**

I created a loop. However, this loop is taking ages (and I am not sure how to add the value to a new column).

Note, in df1 I created a 'Date' column (in the same format as the begin & enddate from df2).

**Key now: How can I add the True value (in the end of the loop..) to my df1 (in an extra column)?**

```
for index, row in df1.interrows(): 
      row['Year'] = str(row['Year'])

      for index1, row1 in df2.iterrows():
          row1['Year'] = str(row1['Year'])


          if row['Year'] == row1['Year']:
                  row['ID'] = str(row['ID']) 
                  row1['ID'] = str(row1['ID']) 


                  if row['ID] == row1['ID']: 

                        if row['Date'] >= row1['BeginDate'] and row['Date'] <= row1['Enddate']:
                              print("I would like to add this YES to df1 in an extra column")
```

**Edit 2**

Trying @davidbilla solution: It looks like the 'condition' column is not doing well. As you can see, it match even while df1.Year != df2.Year. Note that df2 is sorted based on ID (so all the same unique numbers should be there

[image: It looks like the 'condition' column is not doing well. As you can see, it match even while df1.Year != df2.Year. Note that df2 is sorted based on ID (so all the same unique numbers should be there]

Comment: df1 data is missing a Date column.

Comment: Have added it to the example. Thanks for mentioning @cs95.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are expecting something like this - if you are trying to match the dataframes row wise (i.e compare row1 of df1 with row1 of df2):

```
df1['condition'] = np.where((df1['Year']==df2['Year'])&(df1['ID']==df2['ID'])&((df1['Date']>=df2['BeginDate'])or(df1['Date']<=df2['EndDate'])), True, False)
```

np.where takes the conditions as the first parameter, the second parameter will the be the value if the condition pass, the 3rd parameter is the value if the condition fail.

**EDIT 1:**
Based on your sample dataset

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2020,1,123],[2020,1,345],[2020,2,123],[2020,1,123]],
                   columns=['Year','Week','ID'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2020,'2020-01-01  00:00:00','2020-01-02  00:00:00',123],
                    [2020,'2020-01-01  00:00:00','2020-01-02  00:00:00',123],
                    [2020,'2020-01-01  00:00:00','2020-01-02  00:00:00',978],
                    [2020,'2020-09-21  00:00:00','2020-01-02  00:00:00',978]],
                   columns=['Year','BeginDate','EndDate','ID'])
df2['BeginDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['BeginDate'])
df2['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['EndDate'])
df1['condition'] = np.where((df1['Year']==df2['Year'])&(df1['ID']==df2['ID']),True, False)
# &((df1['Date']>=df2['BeginDate'])or(df1['Date']<=df2['EndDate'])) - removed this condition as the df has no Date field
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   Year  Date   ID  condition
0  2020     1  123       True
1  2020     1  345      False
2  2020     2  123      False
3  2020     1  123      False
```

**EDIT 2:** To compare one row in df1 with all rows in df2

```
df1['condition'] = (df1['Year'].isin(df2['Year']))&(df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID']))
```

This takes `df1['Year']` and compares it against all values of `df2['Year']`.

Based on the sample dataset:

df1:

```
   Year       Date   ID  
0  2020 2020-01-01  123  
1  2020 2020-01-01  345  
2  2020 2020-10-01  123  
3  2020 2020-11-13  123
```

df2:

```
   Year  BeginDate    EndDate   ID
0  2020 2020-01-01 2020-02-01  123
1  2020 2020-01-01 2020-01-02  123
2  2020 2020-03-01 2020-05-01  978
3  2020 2020-09-21 2020-10-01  978
```

Code change:

```
date_range = list(zip(df2['BeginDate'],df2['EndDate']))

def check_date(date):
    for (s,e) in date_range:
        if date>=s and date<=e:
            return True
    return False

df1['condition'] = (df1['Year'].isin(df2['Year']))&(df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID']))
df1['date_compare'] = df1['Date'].apply(lambda x: check_date(x)) # you can directly store this in df1['condition']. I just wanted to print the values so have used a new field
df1['condition'] = (df1['condition']==True)&(df1['date_compare']==True)
```

Output:

```
   Year       Date   ID  condition  date_compare
0  2020 2020-01-01  123       True          True    # Year match, ID match and Date is within the range of df2 row 1
1  2020 2020-01-01  345      False          True    # Year match, ID no match
2  2020 2020-10-01  123       True          True    # Year match, ID match, Date is within range of df2 row 4
3  2020 2020-11-13  123      False         False    # Year match, ID match, but Date is not in range of any row in df2
```

**EDIT 3:** 
Based on updated question (Earlier I thought it was ok if the 3 values year, id and date match df2 in any of the rows not on the same row). I think I got better understanding of your requirement now.

```
df2['BeginDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['BeginDate'])
df2['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['EndDate'])
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])

df1['condition'] = False
for idx1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    match = False
    for idx2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if (row1['Year']==row2['Year']) & \
                (row1['ID']==row2['ID']) & \
                (row1['Date']>=row2['BeginDate']) & \
                (row1['Date']<=row2['EndDate']):
            match = True
    df1.at[idx1, 'condition'] = match
```

Output - Set 1:

DF1:

```
   Year       Date   ID
0  2020 2020-01-01  123
1  2020 2020-01-01  123
2  2020 2020-01-01  345
3  2020 2020-01-10  123
4  2020 2020-11-13  123
```

DF2:

```
   Year  BeginDate    EndDate   ID
0  2020 2020-01-15 2020-02-01  123
1  2020 2020-01-01 2020-01-02  123
2  2020 2020-03-01 2020-05-01  978
3  2020 2020-09-21 2020-10-01  978
```

DF1 result:

```
   Year       Date   ID  condition
0  2020 2020-01-01  123       True
1  2020 2020-01-01  123       True
2  2020 2020-01-01  345      False
3  2020 2020-01-10  123      False
4  2020 2020-11-13  123      False
```

Output - Set 2: 
DF1:

```
   Year       Date        ID
0  2019 2019-01-01   s904112
1  2019 2019-01-01   s911243
2  2019 2019-01-01   s917131
3  2019 2019-01-01  sp986214
4  2019 2019-01-01   s510006
5  2020 2020-01-10   s540006
```

DF2:

```
   Year  BeginDate    EndDate       ID
0  2020 2020-01-27 2020-09-02  s904112
1  2020 2020-01-27 2020-09-02  s904112
2  2020 2020-01-03 2020-03-15  s904112
3  2020 2020-04-15 2020-01-05  s904112
4  2020 2020-01-05 2020-05-15  s540006
5  2019 2019-01-05 2019-05-15  s904112
```

DF1 Result:

```
   Year       Date        ID  condition
0  2019 2019-01-01   s904112      False
1  2019 2019-01-01   s911243      False
2  2019 2019-01-01   s917131      False
3  2019 2019-01-01  sp986214      False
4  2019 2019-01-01   s510006      False
5  2020 2020-01-10   s540006       True
```

Comment: Great, I only receive this error (even when I only try to run it for the first expression).     raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled " "Series objects")

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

My data types are similar, and I also used this for both dataframes: df.sort_index(inplace=True)

Comment: @Roverflow In which line are you getting this error? See EDIT 1 where it works for the sample data set you have provided.

Comment: Appreciate your help! Just saw your output, think that the last row should be True (same as the first row). Could it be the case that your solution is not looping over the second df again for the third row?

Comment: @Roverflow This solution is comparing row 1 in df1 with row 1 in df2 and so row 4 in df1 with row 4 in df2 - the ID value is different in row 4 of  df1 and row 4 of df2. Are you expecting to loop through all rows in df2 for each row in df1?

Comment: Hi @Davidbilla, yes it should loop through all rows :-). Is it possible to help me with that?

Comment: @Roverflow see EDIT 2. Can you try this on your data set? This is without the 'Date' field comparison. Are you sure you want to compare each row of `df1.Date` is between any of the rows on `df2.BeginDate` and `df2.EndDate`?

Comment: So Sorry for my late response! When I try your code, I receive an error: 
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'

(on the line where you use the .apply(lambda x: check_date(x))

Many thanks again!

Comment: Did you convert you `df1['Date']` to timestamp using `pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])`?

Comment: That did the trick. It looks like the complete solution is not really working. Please see the updated question (with a print screen).

Comment: @Roverflow see EDIT 3. Earlier I misunderstood your requirement that each row in df1 should match against the 3 values in any rows in df2, but now I understood that it has match in the same row in df2. Check EDIT 3 and let me know if it works for you

Comment: It looks like this is working perfectly. Looped through all the values; thanks!

Comment: @Roverflow Glad that it helped!! Great!! Do I get the bounty? :P

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd row of the desired output has `Year` as `2019`, so I assume the 2nd row of `df1.Year` is also `2019` instead of `2020`

If I understand correctly, you need to merge and filter-out `Date` outside of the `BeginDate` and `EndDate` range. First, there are duplicates and invalid date ranges in `df2`. We need to drop duplicates and invalid ranges before merge. Invalid date ranges are ranges where `BeginDate` >= `EndDate` which is index 3 of `df2`.

```
#convert all date columns of both `df1` and `df2` to datetime dtype
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2[['BeginDate', 'EndDate']] = df2[['BeginDate', 'EndDate']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

#left-merge on `Year`, `ID` and using `eval` to compute 
#columns `Condition` where `Date` is between `BeginDate` and `EndDate`. 
#Finally assign back to `df1`
df1['Condition'] = (df1.merge(df2.loc[df2.BeginDate < df2.EndDate].drop_duplicates(), 
                                on=['Year','ID'], how='left')
                       .eval('Condition= BeginDate <= Date <= EndDate')['Condition'])

Out[614]:
   Year  Week   ID       Date  Condition
0  2020     1  123 2020-01-01       True
1  2019     1  345 2020-01-01      False
2  2020     2  123 2020-01-07      False
3  2020     1  123 2020-01-01       True
```

Comment: Thanks! It gives only "True" when an ID is occurring in DF1, and not in DF2.